# Send multiply input field values to php by using ajax POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, input

I am trying to send some dynamically created input field values to PHP to validate them and make some checks in the database in the background. I don't want to use submit form but just check the fields after click a button.

Html:

```
<input name="clockpick" class="input-mini timeinputfrom" data-format="hh:mm" type="text"></input>
<input name="clockpick" class="input-mini timeinputfrom" data-format="hh:mm" type="text"></input>
<button id="check" class="btn btn-primary">check</button></div>
```

The input boxes can be dynamically created depending how many are necessary. I get the values into jquery but don't find any possibility to send them via post to php.

Jquery:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {

var inputfield = $('input[name="clockpick"]');

 $('input[name="clockpick1"]').each(function( index, element ) {
    console.log( "Wert" + index + ": " + $( element ).val() );          
});


$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "productiontimevalidate.php",
        data: ????

    });
```

How can I send the values / array to PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way would be to add the values to an array, and convert it to json for sending.

```
var allClockPicks = [];
$('input[name="clockpick1"]').each(function( index, element ) {
  allClockPicks.push($(element).val());
});
```

Then, the ajax can send data as

```
data: {cp: JSON.stringify(allClockPicks)}
```

On the php side, you can json_decode them as below:

```
$cpArray = json_decode($_POST['cp'], true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are inside `<form class="my-form"> [elements...] </form>`

You can use this short version:

```
<script>
$.post('/my/path/app.php', $('.my-form').serialize(), function(r) {
   console.log(r);
},'json'); // parse response as JSON
</script>
```

## app.php

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'post', $_POST));
?>
```